# AfxSetResourceHandle does not load all language resources in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, translation

I have a C++ project in VS2013/SP3 and a German language resource DLL which is changed with AfxSetResourceHandle at runtime.

It worked perfectly with VS2012, now when I compile it in VS2013 and run the application all resources are changed to the language resource (Strings, Dialogs) except PropertySheetDialogs, have any ideea what's changed in VS2013 because it does not work anymore ? I use codejock CXTPropertySheet class, but I don't think this has something to do with the resource file.

The projects is exactly the same as before when it worked in VS2012, no changes were made.

When I open the compiled DLL in visual studio it contains all the property sheet dialogs translated correctly, but it seems that AfxSetResourceHandle loads them in English from main EXE, the other resources are loaded correctly from the German DLL.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, nothing subtle since the resource handle for property sheets isn't special.  Create a small repro project so you can be sure it isn't a memory corruption problem or simply forgetting an AFX_MANAGE_STATE() call and attach it with a connect.microsoft.com bug report.  Use Microsoft Support if you can't wait.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the dialog resource to be loaded from the DLL when the propertysheet page is created?

Comment: The `pszTemplate` member of [`CPropertyPage::m_psp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/867zk9f2.aspx) sets the dialog box template to use to create the page.

Comment: ok, I will check that

Comment: I have installed the update 5 CTP, but the same result, I will create an empty propertysheet project to check this outside my app.

Comment: Solved, it was a problem with codejock xtreme toolkit propertysheet, they have introduced a bug in the last version in loaddialogtemplate